# Reduction of a disulfide bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, organosulfur-compounds

I'm trying to reduce a disulfide bond, I've tried 2-mercapto-ethanol, because I've seen in literature that using a thiol is the most common procedure. I carry out the reaction at 80<sup>o</sup> C but so far I have no positive results

Comment: Reveal your reagents and expected products please.

Comment: @permeakra Is very simple indeed I'm trying to reduce the dsulfide bond in cystamine I've used 2-mercaptoaceticacid and 2-mercaptoethanol.

Comment: Here is a good source to look into http://cen.acs.org/articles/90/web/2012/02/Better-Disulfide-Reducing-Agent.html.